# Reachability nodes c++

Tags: c++

I have an unordered_map like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> vertices;
```

where the vertices contain `{{C,B},{A,B},{B,D},{G,E}....}` like below:

```
C B
A B
B D
G E
F E
D E
```

The user will be able to designate the source node, in this case `E` and start from there. The output will look like

```
A - E D B A
B - E D B
C - E D B C
D - E D
E - E
F - E F
G - E G
```

Should I create a vector and keep track of all the nodes that are reached? But for each letter, how will I be able to differentiate what nodes they went into? For example, if A can read `E D B A` and I place them into a vector, the vector will be containing A's reachability and I will no longer be able to place in the other reachability nodes because they will mess everything up.

I tried to do start it like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> reached;
for (auto it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); it++)
{
    for (auto x = vertices.begin(); x != vertices.end(); x++)
    {
        if (it->second == x->first) 
        {
               reached.push_back(it->second);
               //not really sure what to do after?

        }
    }
 }
```

I'm new to C++ so I don't really know how to approach this problem..I'm really confused. Thank you.

Comment: I guess you first need to pick a better structure to hold the results (I can't see how you can print the expected output from a `std::vector<std::string>`, maybe use a vector of vector or a more efficient structure instead). Then you can work on the algo (care about infinite loops)